# looking for a code that gives me an f statistic for bivariate data analysis for survey data

Tags: r

I am a basic r user,

i am researching the mean age at marriage, so for my bivariate analysis, i only calculated the mean age at marriage for various background variables.  with this code:

```
svyby(~V511,~V013,Data92_Design,svymean,na.rm=TRUE)
```

Now, I am trying to get a code that can help me obtain an F statistic  for bivaraite data analysis for survey data. so a code with "svy"
I was only taught how to get means within age groups, now i want an F statistic to show whether the difference between the means was statistically significant.

right now, i have searched for `svychq`, and i am getting errors.

```
svychisq(~V511+V013,Data92_Design,statistic=c("F",  "Chisq","Wald","adjWald","lincom",
 "saddlepoint","wls-score"),na.rm=TRUE)
*Error in solve.default(denom, numr) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 3.01765e-20*
```

Answer (score 0):

For the `statistics =`  part, you pick one option, not **all** of them. Try `statistic = "F"` or `statistic = "Chisq"`, etc. I would see if `statistic = "F"` does the trick.

I suggest that you also look into using the `surveytable` package. It uses `survey` for calculations, but has easier commands.

- Here is a basic usage example: https://cdcgov.github.io/surveytable/
- Here is how to perform testing: https://cdcgov.github.io/surveytable/articles/surveytable.html#numeric-variables